# iOS webView is not using whole screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, tablet, smartphone

I try to show a full responsive bootstrap website in a webView app. The app should just load my website as if I load the website in the browser of the smartphone/tablet.

However, the app looks like this on tablets:

[image]

How can I make the app full responsive?

Whole Code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1  The webView loads the url using an URLRequest object.
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.blizz-z.de/")!

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

        // 2  A refresh item is added to the toolbar which will refresh the current webpage.
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .refresh,
            target: webView,
            action: #selector(webView.reload)
        )

        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        let color = UIColor.black;
        self.view.backgroundColor = color
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }



}
```

Comment: I believe the view rendered here is that for iPhone application. Are you sure the application supports iPADs (is this iPAD or Universal application)

Comment: I need the app to be a universal application for iPad and iPhone

Comment: ok, So you are using size classes right ?

Comment: I don't understand. I am just loading a website.

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: yes I do use storyboard

Comment: And using autolayout ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196621/discussion-between-black-and-rahul).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in your code.
Switch to a target settings in Xcode, on a tab "General" in a section "Deployment target" switch "Devices" to "Universal".
Also add "Launch Screen.storyboard" if you did not add it.

[image]

Comment: Thx! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

you should add constraint for the webView, and the constant of top/bottom/left/right constraint is 0 to superView, not safe area[image]

Comment: I am confused, where do I find this menu? More details needed please.

Comment: Look at right bottom of the screenshot, there you can see a button with arrows. This means that the application is launched in compatibility mode. An iPad  renders the application in an area with same size as size of an iPhone screen (UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds same as on iPhone).

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

 @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupWebview()
    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(
        barButtonSystemItem: .refresh,
        target: webView,
        action: #selector(webView.reload)
    )

    toolbarItems = [refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

 }


 func setupWebview(){
    self.webView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.blizz-z.de/")!
    self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
 }


 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     title = webView.title
 }
}
```

Try this... (Note: Not a copy pasted code)